# Rx when debugging how do i know which scheduler is being used?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

When debugging, how do i find out the type of scheduler which an observable is using to schedule work?

From my understanding, operator Interval and SelectMany seems to be scheduling work using the taskpoolscheduler while other operators aren't behaving similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the operators pick a scheduler that introduces the least concurrency required for the operator.

If you want to know what is being used in the debugger, then put a break point in your observer and look at the stack trace.